# Prop value in child component rerender

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and have 2 questions about rerender behavior. Say a parent component passes a state to a child component as a prop. If the state changes, does the child component gets rerendered twice? I think so since first the state change triggers rerender in parent and parent rerender triggers child rerender, and second prop change in child component also triggers child to rerender. Is my under standing correct?
My 2nd question is, if the child component gets rerendered twice as I said above, what's the prop value in the 1st rerender? Does it still have the old value since this rerender is not triggered by prop change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a state per se to the child element from a parent. But you can pass a reference to a function that updates a parent's state. When a child calls it, the parent will be rendered once and child will get rendered once. Consider the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ChildEl = ({ updateParentState }) => {
  console.log("Rendering child");
  return (
    <div>
      Child ELemente
      <button onClick={() => updateParentState("some value from child")}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [ss, setSS] = React.useState("Original value");
  console.log("Rendering parent");
  const updateState = (v) => setSS(v);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{ss}</h2>
      <ChildEl updateParentState={updateState} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

On first render both parent and child get rendered once. Then when you click the button inside the child which updates a state variable in the parent, the same thing happens - both parent and child are rendered once. Here is the Sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-tdd-mznbb?file=/src/App.js
Take a look at the console as you render those elements.

If you pass a state variable to the Child component (in the above example it's the `ss` variable), then nothing happens when you mutate it inside the Child as it become a mere local variable so nothing will get re-rendered in that scenario.

Comment: thx for your answer. What I mean is passing a parent state to the child as the child's prop. That's possible, right? In that case, if parent updates that state, will child be re-rendered twice and if so what's the prop value in 1st re-render?

Comment: What do you mean by "passing a parent state"? Do you mean passing a parent's state variable as a prop? If so, the last paragraph answer that question. Otherwise, there is no way to a "pass a parent state".

Comment: yes, I mean passing a parent's state variable as a prop. But I want to know what happens if later parent updates that state instead of child updating that variable.

Comment: @FeiQu In that case both Parent and Child will get re-rendered just one time. Here is the Sandbox link to test it. Again, look at the console output: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-tdd-mznbb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I c. Got it. Thx for your explanation. So react is smart enough to know both triggers of re-rendering is caused by the same state change and only re-render child once.

Comment: @FeiQu Yep, Indeed.